# docker compose stringArray for --file

Tags: arrays, string, docker, docker-compose

I have recently installed `Docker Compose version v2.4.1`

Normally I can run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.kafka.yml` to start up but somehow this time there's no errors and kept on showing me `Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND`

I thought `-f` was deprecated or something but no it isn't and instead it's still there.
By reading through the `--help` closer and the docker compose documentation online I found that now `-f` uses `stringArray`

```
-f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
```

which docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/ still shows

```
-f, --file FILE             Specify an alternate compose file
```

Also found a post talking about it https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8773.

However, I do not see an example of how the `stringArray` works so I am still not able to get `-f` to work.

By any chance someone to correctly use `-f` with this new version of `docker compose`?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: Do you have a Compose command like `up` or `ps` at the end of the command?  (Would it be a valid command without the `-f filename.yml` option?)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes `up` `ps` `down` `stop` works fine
`docker-compose up` itself would work fine

Comment: So the actual command is `docker-compose -f filename.yml up`?  I could see that error if `up` wasn't there.

Comment: @DavidMaze The regular command I used before was `docker-compose -f docker-compose.kafka.yml up -d` which worked fine because it's accepting `-f` as `FILE` for previous versions but now it's accepting `-f` as `stringArray` which I tried a few values but did not work.